# Копипаст ответа с другого сайта

Tags: обсуждение

*Казалось что данный вопрос уже поднимался, но не нашел на мете. Если это дубликат - удалю*

---

Суть вопроса:
Ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1181237/177613 является копипастой учебника (причем ссылка на источник в ответе присутствует). Не уверен что это запрещено, хотя на мой взгляд это не хорошо. Какие мнения у сообщества?

Comment: Можете немного раскрыть мысль? Почему Вы считаете, что это нехорошо?

Answer (score 3):

Если ссылка на источник указана, то точно всё нормально.

Comment: Только вот я сомневаюсь, что источник просто так разрешает перелицензировать себя на CC BY-SA 4.0...

Comment: @andreymal, а зачем ему перелецинзироваться, если он - цитата?

Comment: Ну как минимум на данный момент она не оформлена как цитата

Comment: @andreymal, думаю, это неважно.

Comment: Думаю, статья 1274 ГК РФ за такие вольности наваляет юридических люлей

Comment: @andreymal, бороться надо, чтобы не было таких статей (да и таких законодателей тоже)

Comment: @andreymal, а что там не так?

Comment: @avp а вот тут я боюсь, что выход России из Бернской конвенции нанесёт гораздо больший вред, чем присутствие таких статей :(

Comment: @Qwertiy как минимум авторство не указано (возможно ещё что-нибудь, но я не юрист чтобы в тонкостях разбираться)

Comment: @andreymal, ну указать не проблема. Я как-то не подумал, что ссылка на источник != авторство.

Comment: @andreymal, бороться надо во всемирном масштабе, чтобы от таких конвенций всюду камня на камне бы не осталось

Comment: @Qwertiy там ещё и ссылка на источник не оформлена как ссылка на источник, а это уже важно...